# How to send different Model (not declared) from View to Controller?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have View with a table of products. I am trying to add new inputs at the top of table if `btnAdd` was clicked. Then press Save a send data to the controller. I understand that if I do submit, it sends declared datatype to the controller at the top of the view. In my case `IndexViewModel`. But I want to send an instance of `Product` model back to the controller.

I have controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          IndexViewModel _IndexViewModel = new IndexViewModel()
          // some code
          return View(_IndexViewModel );
      }
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Insert(Product product)
      {
          // some code
      }
}
```

Two models:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And View:

```
@model TestApp.ViewModels.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div>
    <input type="button" value="btnAdd"/>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th/>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="new-row" hidden>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <td><input type="text" id="newProductName"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="newProductPrice"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="newProductQuantity"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save"/>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
            @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@product.Name"</td>
                    <td>@product.Price"</td>
                    <td>@product.Quantity"</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I was trying do .js function and call if on the Save button, but it did not work:

```
function save() {
    var newProduct = {};
    newProduct.Name = $('#newProductName').val();
    newProduct.Price = $('#newProductPrice').val();
    newProduct.Quantity = $('#newProductQuantity').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "Product/Insert",
        type: 'post',
        data: '{product: ' + JSON.stringify(newProduct) + '}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Failed");
        }

    })
}
```

Is there any way how to pass `Product` model to `Insert` action?

Comment: This will helps you https://forums.asp.net/t/2087551.aspx?Post+data+from+Two+different+models+in+MVC+at+one+go+one+in+a+partial+view+and+the+other+in+main+view+

Comment: What you mean _"but it did not work"_?

Comment: Have you tried marking your Controller with [JsonResult]? Also, are you getting any error? Are you getting a request on the Server but either your Model is not binding or the routing is not configured? You can check it by using Global.asax and registering a function using ModelBinders.Binders.Add(<>,<>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need add name same as property of `Product` class without jquery AJAX

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <td><input type="text" id="newProductName" name="Name" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="newProductPrice" name="Price" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="newProductQuantity" name="Quantity" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" />
                </td>
            }
```